# how to pass slider value to next column of same row using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function(position, value) {
     var targetset = colCell1 / value;
     console.log($(this).closest('tr.jqgrow td:nth-child(6)').next().html(
       targetset));
     var nthchild = $("tr.jqgrow").find("td").innerHTML;
     $(this).closest('tr.jqgrow td:nth-child(6)').next().html(
       targetset);
}
```

I got **targetset** value now i need to pass that value to next column of same row.

Comment: can you share full code with html?

Comment: $(this).append($("<div style='text-align:center;'><div style='padding:14px;'><input type='range' id='slider' min='" + min + "' max='" + max + "' step='1' value='3' data-rangeslider><output id='val'></output></div></div>"));  this is my slider which will be one column of my table and next to this column i have another column . I need to pass slider output to that next column.

Answer (score 0):

You can add value to next column of same row like this

```js
 var targetset = 'This is targetest value'
            var valueColumn = $('td:nth-child(1)');
                $(valueColumn).next().attr('value',targetset)
```

Comment: What is 'value'  in attr you mean??

Comment: I think you got value in targetset variable then i just pass this value in next column as attr.

Comment: It says **jQuery.fn.attr('value', val) no longer sets properties**

Comment: can you share full code html with jquery/javascript?

Comment: $(this).append($("<div style='text-align:center;'><div style='padding:14px;'><input type='range' id='slider' min='" + min + "' max='" + max + "' step='1' value='3' data-rangeslider><output id='val'></output></div></div>")); this is my slider .This will be one column of my table .on slide i m getting a value . i need to pass this value to next column

Comment: <div ><table class="ui-jqgrid-htable" ><thead><tr ><th id="buy_div_Target"><div id="jqgh_buy_div_Target">Target</div></th></tr></thead></table></div><table id="buy_div" style="float: left; clear: both; width: 1458.2px;"  class="ui-jqgrid-btable"><tbody><tr class="jqgfirstrow" ></tr><tr role="row" id="3" tabindex="-1" class="ui-widget-content "><td>0.00</td></tr><tr  id="4" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr myAltRowClass"><td >0.00</td></tr></tbody></table> this my target where i have to pass that slider value